# Getting date in a Batch file

Tags: batch

I know nothing about batch files and I need to automate an application. The application has two fields

1. Today's date
2. Yesterday's date

In the batch file I have the application's location and my log in information.
And additionally I need these two dates. How can I get the dates via batch file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the Date in a batch file in a predictable format?](http://superuser.com/questions/315984/how-to-get-the-date-in-a-batch-file-in-a-predictable-format)

Comment: For yesterday's date see [so] question [dos batch programming: howto get and display yesterday date](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2954359)

Answer (score 14):

On a Microsoft Windows system, you can obtain the current date using the `date /t` command (the `/t` option prevents the command from prompting for a change to the the date) or by using `echo %date%` to display the contents of the date environment variable. However, both of those display the date in the form `DDD mm/dd/yyyy`, if the system uses a U.S. date format for displaying dates, where DDD is the day of the week represented by a 3-character abbreviation, e.g., "Thu", mm is a two-digit representation of the month, e.g., "08" for August, dd is the day and yyyy is the year.

```
C:\>date /t
Thu 08/06/2015

C:\>echo %date%
Thu 08/06/2015
```

You can reformat the representation of the date that is stored in the `%date%` environment variable. E.g, if you wanted the date in the form yyyymmdd, you can use a command like the one below where a variable, `YYYYMMDD` is set to hold the reformatted date; the variable name can be anything you like, e.g., mydate, etc.

```
C:\>set YYYYMMDD=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%

C:\>echo %YYYYMMDD%
20150806
```

The substring arguments to extract the elements of the date string are in the format `%variable:~startposition,numberofchars%`, so if the "T" in Thursday in the string "Thu 08/06/2015" is at position 0, the 10th character is the "2" of 2015 and I want 4 characters, i.e., "2015", so `%DATE:10,4%` will give me those characters. Or you can also think of the first number as the numer of characters to be skipped, i.e., `%variable:~num_chars_to_skip,numberofchars%`. I can then append `%DATE:~4,2%` to get "08" for the month followed by `%DATE:~7,2%` to extract the day, i.e., "06" if the date is August 6, 2015 represented in the `%DATE%` variable as "Thu 08/06/2015". [Reference with additional links](http://support.moonpoint.com/blog/blosxom/2014/11/22#YYYYMMDD)

If your batch file may be used on systems in other countries, though, you may need to make adjustments for a different style of date display other than month/day/year if you are reformatting the date rather than just displaying it in whatever format is the default one for the system. If you issue a `reg query` command, you can see the default format for the system. E.g.:

```
C:\>reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sShortDate

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International
    sShortDate    REG_SZ    M/d/yyyy
```

In the above example, I can see the system is using the month/day/year format. The setting for the country can be seen with `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /v sCountry`, but that may not be some thing you have to concern yourself with if you know the systems are local ones using a default date representation.

For ways to get yesterday's date there are several Stack Overflow postings, including the one mentioned by DavidPostill:

[How to get yesterday's date in batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010670/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-in-batch-file)

[how to get yesterday's date in DOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11891335/how-to-get-yesterdays-date-in-dos)

[dos batch programming: howto get and display yesterday date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954359/dos-batch-programming-howto-get-and-display-yesterday-date)

Answer (score 1):

Slightly OT, but if you are able to use PowerShell instead of CMD.EXE, it all gets much easier, e.g. you can use the `Get-Date` expression and a `UFormat` specifier, as documented [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Get-Date?view=powershell-5.1), to do exactly what you want.  Powershell also makes it easier to do sensible arithmetic on dates, eg it knows that the day before 1 Jan 2025 is not 0 Jan 2025.

PowerShell is standard on versions of Windows going back to at least Windows 7.

Examples (here, `PS >` is a prompt in the interactive PowerShell ISE window):

```
PS > $oldfile = "backup." + (get-date (get-date).addDays(-1) -UFormat "%Y%m%d")
PS > $newfile = "backup." + (get-date -UFormat "%Y%m%d")

PS > echo $oldfile
backup.20171027
PS > echo $newfile
backup.20171028
```