# Batch file where to get date as MM.dd.yyyy for backup folder name

Tags: batch, date

In below code I want to create a daily wise folder with hostname for backup where the date format shall be `MM.dd.yyyy`.

I'm using `set mydate=%date:/=%` and `Echo %mydate%` to get thedate. But I'm getting dd-MM-yyyy format.

As the system format is dd-MM-yyyy %date% not providing desired format.

**My script so far:**

```
@echo off

REM Getting Host Name
FOR /F "usebackq" %%i IN (`hostname`) DO SET host=%%i
ECHO %host%

REM Getting System Date & Time
set mydate=%date:/=%
Echo %mydate%
set mytime=%time:~-11,2%-%time:~-8,2%-%time:~-5,2%
set mytimestamp=%mydate: =%_%mytime:.=%
echo %mytimestamp%
REM This timestamp is used to create folder System Name with date
set mynewtimestamp=%host%_%mydate: =%
echo %mynewtimestamp%
Rem Change the WINRAR Installation path & MSSQL OSQL.exe path in below statement, seperated with semicolumn.
set path=C:\Program Files\WinRAR;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\150\Tools\Binn;C:\WINDOWS\System32;

Rem Change patch in following statement as per Required "BackupDest1" (Centrlise Location) Installation.
set BackupDest=D:\Daily_Backup\Backup\

REM CREATING BACKUP WITH RAR FORMAT

rar a -ep1 "%BackupDest%\%mytimestamp%_TEST.rar" "C:\Program Files\TEST"

REM MSSQL DB BACKUP

"osql.exe" -E -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [TEST] TO DISK='%BackupDest%\%mytimestamp%_MSSQL_TEST.bak' WITH FORMAT"
rar a -epl "%BackupDest%\%mytimestamp%_SQL_Backup.rar" "%BackupDest%*.bak"

pushd "%BackupDest%"
del *.bak
del *.reg
md %BackupDest%\%mynewtimestamp% 2>NUL
ROBOCOPY "D:\Daily_Backup\Backup" "%BackupDest%\%mynewtimestamp%" /z /MOV /MT32
```

Comment: stop using `%date%` and `%time%`, they're locale dependent. Duplicate: [How can I get the date in a locale independent format in a batch file?](https://superuser.com/q/1287756/241386), [How to get the date in a batch file in a predictable format?](https://superuser.com/q/315984/241386)

Answer (score 0):

Use a one liner from powershell for this and save yourself the hassle.

Yes, ***I know you are using batch and not powershell***.  I shell out to powershell for the finite stuff.. FROM MY BATCH FILE like this..

`for /f %%a in ('powershell -Command "Get-Date -format MM.dd.yyyy"') do set datetime=%%a`

This is how I would solve this and I am very adept at batch.  Sure I could parse the commands from batch but why?  In this case, the easiest route is probably also the best route.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f usebackq^tokens^=4delims^=^<^>. %%G in =;(`
    "%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe" OS Get localdatetime /format:xml ^| find "VALUE"
    `);= do set "_dt=%%~G"

set "_BackupDest=D:\Daily_Backup\Backup\"
set "_Rar="c:\program files\winrar\rar.exe""
set "_osql="c:\program files\microsoft sql server\150\tools\binn\osql.exe""
set "_var=%ComputerName%_%_dt:~4,2%/%_dt:~6,2%/%_dt:~0,4%-%_dt:~8,2%-%_dt:~10,2%-%_dt:~12,2%"

%_rar% a -ep1 "%_BackupDest%\%_var%_TEST.rar" "C:\Program Files\TEST"
%_osql% -E -Q "Backup Database [Test] To Disk='%_BackupDest%\%_var%_MSSQL_Test.bak' With Format"
%_rar% a -epl "%_BckupDest%\%_var%_SQL_Backup.rar" "%_BackupDest%*.bak"

pushd "%_BackupDest%" && 2>nul =;( del *.bak *.reg & mkdir "%_BackupDest%\%_var%" 
    Robocopy "D:\Daily_Backup\Backup" "%_BackupDest%\%_var%" /z /mov /mt32
   );= & popd & endlocal
```

---

**1.** Change your command for obtaining date and time to one that does not suffer changes due to user settings, customizations, language, etc... and compose substrings relevant to the desired layout

**2.** ComputerName returns the hostname without using a loop, which ultimately only complicates your code for the same result

**3.** Do not use the path name for the variable name, you can use your command customizations without messing with the system variable (only recommended)

**4.** Documenting the code is helpful, but yours has a lot of comments for the same actions, summarize your command and your comments.